# why getting the current location using google map and android sometimes return the last location not the current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created app which work with the google map and it works fine with the google map services. but one problem appear which it is .
when I request the current location sometimes it work fine and return the exact current location but other times it return the last current location 
where I am not in.
who can provide me solution
this is the code

```
private GoogleApiClient mLocationclient;
GoogleMap mMap;             

// connect client to the map by take his location
            mLocationclient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            mLocationclient.connect();
            // end connect
```

// get the current location

```
public LatLng getCurrentLocation(Context context, GoogleMap mMaps,GoogleApiClient mlocationclient){
    LatLng ll=null;
    Location currentLocation= LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mlocationclient);
    if(currentLocation==null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"could not connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
            ll=new LatLng(
                currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                currentLocation.getLongitude()
        );
    }
    return ll;
}
```

Comment: because that was the last time it was able to get a successful location. If you need something really accurate then you should get a one time location using the request location updates

Comment: so what is the problem prevent it form getting the current location next time. and did U mean the listen to change current location

Comment: yes you need to listen for a one time location change

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `getLastLocation();` that will return the last time your GPS device was able to fetch a location.

If you want to force the device to fetch a location try:

```
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    lat = loc.getLatitude();
    lng = loc.getLongitude();
```

Further, you can take a look at this reference for more informaton. [requestSingleUpdate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate(java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper))

Comment: is it the same as requestLocationUpdates and what is the lm ?

Comment: No, you would use requestLocationUpdates if you want to request regular updates on location. Where as requestSingleUpdate would request a single update at a point in time. lm is Location Manager

Comment: ok listen up . my app is move camera to current location listen to the click on button what is the best way to do it

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to move your device to a certain location then press a button to get the location? If so you would use requestSingleUpdate in this case.

Comment: No I want to press the button then the app must display the current location where the client is.

Comment: @NahamSoft Okay, in this case you would use the code that I gave you to get the current location. Then feed that lat and long into Google Maps API to display on the screen.

Comment: Would be better to use a LocationListener for the `requestSingleUpdate()` call, and don't use `getLastKnownLocation()` at all.  That would guarantee that the new Location is used.

Comment: @NahamSoft If my code helped you find a solution please mark question correct.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps uses the last known location in the event that it does not have the exact current location. The GPS takes time to locate the users exact position, and therefor the app uses previous latitude and longitude until the GPS gets a fix.

Check this link out: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html